# How to display different videos depending on media size?

Tags: html, html5-video

I intend to run a background video on a webpage, I have different video-files for mobile and one for desktop. I

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="desktop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="desktop.webm" type="video/webm">
  <img src="fallback.jpg" >
</video>
```

I have seen a media-query type solution but as far as I can understand it's going out of the specc and is not supported by ios/safari.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to use a src or another depending on its definition. Check this post on CSS-Tricks https://css-tricks.com/video-source-by-screen-size/ 
BUT it looks like is not an stable feature on all browsers.

```
<video controls> 
   <source src="video-small.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width: 480px)"> 
   <source src="video-small.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (max-width: 480px)"> 
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
   <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"> 
</video>
```

The alternative as it says the post would be change the video src with Javascript depending on the viewport size.

Comment: For anyone coming to this in 2020, the media attribute is no longer supported or in the spec for non-picture elements (including video).

Comment: @RobW so basically there´s no other way to show/hide video at different resolutions, other than using the "display" property?

Comment: I have no idea , haven't worked in that space in quite a while

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest solution is to show/hide each video according to screen size using CSS media queries.

[EDIT: As suggested by ToddPadwick in the comments, I've added the [CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content-visibility) "content-visibility". It's still experimental and [not compatible with Safari](https://caniuse.com/?search=content-visibility) at the moment, but it looks very useful and effective.]

HTML

```
<div id="MyHomepage">
    <video muted autoplay loop id="HD-Video">
        <source src="Video_HD1080.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video muted autoplay loop id="SD-Video">
        <source src="Video_SD600.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1919px) {
    #HD-Video {
        display: none;
        content-visibility: hidden;
    }
}
    
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    #SD-Video {
        display: none;
        content-visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, but it will download both videos. it would be nice to have a way, similar to picture tag

Comment: You might wish to use Content visibility to tell the browser not to load the other video. as Display none still downloads both assets which is not good for performance https://web.dev/articles/content-visibility

Comment: @ToddPadwick I didn't know, thanks for the info ;) I've modified my post